# How to align SearchBar to left or right side in React Bootstrap table2

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am struggling with the Search bar position. By default, my search bar is aligned on the left side but I want to align it to right side. I tried `searchPosition="right"` but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<ToolkitProvider
    keyField="subSourceId"
    data={this.state.selSubFundingSource}
    columns={columns}
    search={{ searchFormatted: true }}
    hover
    filter={filterFactory()}
>
    {
        props => (
            <div>
                <hr />
                <SearchBar
                searchPosition="right"
                {...props.searchProps} />
                <ClearSearchButton {...props.searchProps} />
                <BootstrapTable noDataIndication="Data not found" tabIndexCell
                    pagination={paginationFactory(options)}
                    rowEvents={{
                        onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
                            this.editSource(row);
                        }
                    }}
                    {...props.baseProps}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
</ToolkitProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css:

```
.search-label{
   float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a div element to the search box and control it. If it doesnt work add one more beneath it and you could control it.

```
<ToolkitProvider
    keyField="subSourceId"
    data={this.state.selSubFundingSource}
    columns={columns}
    search={{ searchFormatted: true }}
    hover
    filter={filterFactory()}
>
    {
        props => (
            <div>
                <hr />
              <div className = "abc">
                <SearchBar
                searchPosition="right"
                {...props.searchProps} />
              </div>
                <ClearSearchButton {...props.searchProps} />
                <BootstrapTable noDataIndication="Data not found" tabIndexCell
                    pagination={paginationFactory(options)}
                    rowEvents={{
                        onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
                            this.editSource(row);
                        }
                    }}
                    {...props.baseProps}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
</ToolkitProvider>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can try to use this method use the style={{ float:"right"}} on the

```
 <ToolkitProvider
        keyField="asset_id"
        data={arrangeData(data.asset)}
        columns={assetColumns}
        search
      >
        {(props) => (
          <div>
            <SearchBar
              {...props.searchProps}
              style={{ width: "250px", float: "right" }}
            />
            <br />
            <br />

            <BootstrapTable
              bordered={false}
              pagination={paginationFactory(options)}
              selectRow={selectAssetRow}
              {...props.baseProps}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </ToolkitProvider>
```